# Type Member "Age" is not supported in LINQ to Entities when using ODataQueryOptions

Tags: c#, linq

We constantly select data like this in our application:

```
 myDummyService.getAll().Where(x => x.Id > 1000).Select(x => new DummyDto() {
     Id = x.Id,
     Name = x.Name
 };
```

This will return an `IQueryable`, and a `DummyDto` looks like this:

```
public class DummyDto {
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int Age {get;set;}
}
```

As soon as we use `ODataQueryOptions` to implement paging, this results in the error:

`The specified type member "Age" is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.`

"Age" is just another property of DummyDto that we are not selecting in the code above.

We implement paging like this:

```
public PageResult<DummyDto> GetAll(ODataQueryOptions<DummyDto> queryOptions) {
    var result = queryOptions.applyTo(
               myDummyService.getAll().Where(x => x.Id > 1000).Select(x => new DummyDto() {
                      Id = x.Id,
                      Name = x.Name
               })
    });

    return new PageResult<DummyDto>(results as IEnumerable<DummyDto>);
```

If we would change the query to this, the error disappears.

```
public PageResult<DummyDto> GetAll(ODataQueryOptions<DummyDto> queryOptions) {
    var result = queryOptions.applyTo(
               myDummyService.getAll().Where(x => x.Id > 1000).Select(x => new DummyDto() {
                      Id = x.Id,
                      Name = x.Name,
                      Age = null // simply set the property to null, because we don't want / need it in this case
               })
    });
```

Anyone have any idea why?

Comment: Can you show the definition of `DummyDto` ?

Comment: Added the definition of DummyDto. It has three properties (or more) while we only need two.

Comment: use int? to define age and id so null values are acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the `queryOptions.applyTo()` is trying to apply th eoptions to each property of the class, but can't with `Age` since it's not connect to the database object.

How 'bout we just create a new class, just to this?

```
public class DummyDto2 {
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Yeah we know that this is also a possibility, but that would also mean creating a custom dto for each time we select specific fields, which we don't want to do either because it's kind of overkill

Answer (score 0):

Age is not null able value in your model and force fully assign null value that's why getting error .

Declare your Property like this model

```
public int? Age {get;set;}
```